# JUnit error while comparing two XML's after transformation

Tags: java, xml, junit

Hi I get the following error when i try to execute my JUNIT test case. If somebody can help me with this, it would be of great help.

org.junit.ComparisonFailure: Line: 0: Current output does not match with expected output

```
expected result[0]: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?><ROOT>
current  result[0]: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
expected:<...oding="iso-8859-1"?>[<ROOT>]> but was:<...oding="iso-8859-1"?>[]>
    at org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:123)
    at xslt_test.utils.AssertUtil.assertLinesEquals(AssertUtil.java:14)
    at xslt_test.Test_IngestRequest.testRun_BaselineFileCompare_Schedule(Test_XXXRequest.java:47)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.runTest(TestCase.java:168)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.runBare(TestCase.java:134)
    at junit.framework.TestResult$1.protect(TestResult.java:110)
    at junit.framework.TestResult.runProtected(TestResult.java:128)
    at junit.framework.TestResult.run(TestResult.java:113)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.run(TestCase.java:124)
    at junit.framework.TestSuite.runTest(TestSuite.java:232)
    at junit.framework.TestSuite.run(TestSuite.java:227)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit38ClassRunner.run(JUnit38ClassRunner.java:83)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:49)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

Comment: The <ROOT> part is missing? I don't understand what you're actually asking us.

Comment: Show us some of your test code, do you test it as an xml file, or a text file ? looks like the expected result has the first starting node in the first line but the actual result has this first starting node maybe in the second line